# How to set parent scope for ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that needs an isolated scope for its work
one of the parameters it receives is a templateUrl that it pass on to ng-include

Is there a way to tell ng-include to generate its scope as a child scope of the parent scope that called my directive? (the same thing that happens with ng-transclude - except that i am already using transclude inside, and i need an additional template.

You can view the current directive https://github.com/lee-elenbaas/angular-multiline-ellipsis
It will become much more usable is the ellipsisUrl will be transcluded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, what you want is to exclude a part of the directive's template from the isolated scope and transclude it back to the parent scope.

#### I would go with a directive

```js
.directive('excludeFromIsolated', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
      $transclude(scope.$parent), function(clone){
        elm.replaceWith(clone);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

#### In your template wrap the element which contains `ngInclude` with the new directive:

```js
+ '<exclude-from-isolated>'
  + '<span ng-include="ellipsis" ng-style="ellipsisStyle"></span>'
+ '</exclude-from-isolated>'
```

#### Considerations

- I considered using `scope.$parent.$new()` but it is pointless since `ngInclude` creates a new scope anyway.
- `ngInlcude` already using transclusion
- Angular do not allow duplicate transclusion on the same element (unless you use $$tlb which you probably shouldn't mess with), so I had to wrap it with an element.